# pd$(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha)=\sup\limits_{\alpha\in A}\{$pd$(M_\alpha)\}$

Tags: homological-algebra

I came across the following problem in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra:

11.69.  If $\{M_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of left R-modules, prove that pd$(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha)=\sup\limits_{\alpha\in A}\{$pd$(M_\alpha)\}$, where pd denotes the projective dimension.

For now I am just looking at the case where pd$(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha)<\infty$.  Here is my attempt:

Let

$0\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow ... \rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\xrightarrow{\epsilon}\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha\rightarrow 0$

be a projective resolution of minimal length.  Then for each $\alpha$,

$0\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow ... \rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\xrightarrow{p_\alpha\epsilon}M_\alpha\rightarrow 0$

is a projective resolution where $p_\alpha$ is the appropriate projection.  Hence pd$M_\alpha\leq$ pd $(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha),     \thinspace \forall\alpha\in A$.  So pd $(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha)$ is an upper bound for $\{$pd$ M_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$.

But I still need to show that it is the least upper bound.  Any hints on how to show this last part as well as any corrections to my proof of the first part are appreciated.

Comment: Why is $0\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\xrightarrow{p_\alpha\circ\epsilon}M_\alpha\rightarrow 0$ still exact at $P_0$? I would expect $\ker(p_\alpha\circ\epsilon) \supsetneq \ker(\epsilon)$…

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct, I wasn't being careful enough.  I guess I am back to square one.  Any hints?

Comment: For one direction, note projective resolutions of the $M_\alpha$ can be summed together to give a projective resolution for $M$. In the other direction, what comes to mind for me is to use Tor, but I don't know if Rotman has covered that yet.

Comment: I am not sure how Tor would be useful here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Ext. See Lemma 11.123, and use Proposition 10.81.